# Como pegar ID do registro que é populado na ListView

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

Como faço pra pegar o ID da ListView? Segue meu código resumido:

## UPDATE

**Como faço pra pegar o ID DO REGISTRO que é populado pelo SQLite na ListView.**

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource;        
    
    private static final String[] campos = {"nomeObjeto", "nomePessoa", "_id"};
    
    ListView listView;
    BaseDAO helper;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvObjetosEmprestados);
        
        helper = new BaseDAO(this);        
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        AtualizarObjetos();
    }    
    
    
    public void AtualizarObjetos(){    
       dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.objetosemprestadosrow, objetosEmprestados, campos, new int [] {R.id.lblNomeObjeto, R.id.lblEmprestadoPara});
       listView.setAdapter(dataSource);            
    }
}
```

Comment: O que quer dizer com ID da ListView? Pelo código postado é `R.id.lvObjetosEmprestados`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponho que você se está referindo ao ID do registo que corresponde à linha que é clicada.

Para isso você necessita de declarar e atribuir um `OnItemClickListener` à `ListView`

```java
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {

        // id é o valor que você procura
    }
});
```

Comment: Tá dando esse erro: **The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})**

Comment: Veja se foi feito correctamente o `import` para a classe `OnItemClickListener` que deverá ser: `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;`

Comment: valeo, deu certo (:

Answer (score 0):

Pelo seu código o id é R.id.lvObjetosEmprestados. Mas dá pra pegar usando essa função que toda view tem: listView.getId();

Lembrando que R.id.lvObjetosEmprestados deve estar no layout activity_main e ser de uma listview. Senão vai quebrar.